# ELMAH Page Missing Timestamp and Username

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, elmah

We recently began using ELMAH in our project and I'm noticing some weird issues on the summary page /elmah.axd.

Everything seems to be in proper order -- except for the timestamp / username.  They seem to be empty.

Username is string.empty and the date/time is defaulting to 1/1/0001    12:00 AM.

Clicking on the details of an error will show you the proper timestamp and user -- and the database table appears to have proper values.
3demo14
2011-08-29 17:09:40.410

Is there a configuration step I missed somewhere?

```
<elmah>
<security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmahErrorConnectionString" />
</elmah>  

<!-- elmah -->    
<add name="elmahErrorConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ElmahLLSFDev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SNIP;Password=SNIP"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />     
<!-- end elmah -->

<!-- elmah modules -->      
<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
<add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
<add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
<add name="ErrorTweet" type="Elmah.ErrorTweetModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />      
<!-- end elmah modules-->

<!-- elmah handlers -->      
<add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />      
<!-- end elmah -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The config looks good.  Probably just a bad version.  I'd say go get the latest code and compile it yourself.

If you are still experiencing the problem, it's open source so you can absolutely look under the hood to see what's going on.